# c++ error : cannot convert 'const std::basic_string<char>' to 'int' in assignment

Tags: c++, string, templates

How can I fix it? In main function, when I trying to make new node has string data, it can't. Error message is  [Error] cannot convert 'const std::basic_string' to 'int' in assignment. How can I do it??

```
template <typename value_type>
class node : public element
    public :
    value_type data;
    node();
    node (const value_type& T);
    ~node();
};
template <typename value_type>
node<value_type> :: node(const value_type& T)
{
    type = 0;
    intd= 0;
    stringd = "";
    if(typeid(T)==typeid(int))
    {
        type= 0;intd = T;
    }
    else if(typeid(T)==typeid(string))
    {
        type = 3;stringd = T;
    }
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
    this->data = T;
}
int main()
{
    string s1 = "123";
    node *n1 = new node<string>(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `typeid` for that, please... `type= 0;intd = T;` still has to compile, even if the condition is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
if(typeid(T)==typeid(int))
{
    type= 0;intd = T;   // *** here ***
}
```

Although you *dynamically* check `typeid(T)==typeid(int)` before you assign `T` to an `int` variable, C++ is *statically* typed. The assignment won't compile, because you cannot assign a `string` to an `int` variable.

Instead, you can use template specialization:

```
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using std::string;
struct element{
    int type, intd;
    string stringd;
    void *left, *right;
};

template <typename value_type>
class node : public element{
    public :
    value_type data;
    node();
    node (const value_type& T);
    ~node();
};

template <typename value_type>
node<value_type> :: node(const value_type& T)
{
    type = 0;
    intd= 0;
    stringd = "";
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
    this->data = T;
}

template <>
node<int> :: node(const int& T)
{
    type= 0;
    intd = T;
    stringd = "";
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
    this->data = T;
}

template <>
node<string> :: node(const string& T)
{
    type = 3;
    intd= 0;
    stringd = T;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
    this->data = T;
}

// defining destructor is required to use delete
template <typename value_type>
node<value_type> :: ~node()
{
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = "123";
    node<string> *n1 = new node<string>(s1);
    delete n1;
    return 0;
}
```

I also

- added `{` after `class node : public element`.
- changed type of `n1` from `node` to `node<string>` to avoid compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll eventually want to put your Node object into some kind of container like a linked list. Containers don't handle elements of different types. You can store void * pointers in the container to hide their internal details. But then you're giving up compiler type-checking.

One way of getting type-checking back is to hide the mechanics of holding multiple types in a class like boost::variant. Your `Node` object then does not need to be templated because you declare `data` as:

```
boost::variant<int, string> data;
```

`boost::variant<int, string>` will handle `int` and `string` only, but you can add more template parameters to handle more types, eg `boost::variant<int, string, double>`.

If you're interested in looking under the hood of how to handle this difficult issue, check out this great seminal article by Volker Simonis and Roland Weiss: http://www.progdoc.de/papers/nseq/nseq/nseq.html